# floating div elements right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I really have a hard time placing a div tag. I need to get my form-box with the yellow border out to the right, and my text Inbound Marketing and subtext in the middle. Can anybody help me through this one?

> - The text is laying in the div with a green border.
> - The background picture is laying in the div with a red border

Here is my code what I tried until now.
My code looks like this:

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="top-area" style="border: 4px solid red;">
        <div class="container" style="border: 4px solid green;">
           <div class="form-container" style="border: 4px solid yellow;">
                <div>
                    @Umbraco.RenderMacro("Ebook")
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1 class="header-xl center">
                  @Html.Raw(headerText)
            </h1>
            <p class="sub-header center">
                 @Html.Raw(CurrentPage.imageTeaserText)
            </p>
        </div>
   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.top-area {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

    .top-area, .top-area > .container {
        min-height: 500px;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
    }

        .top-area > .container {
            -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items:center;
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .top-area p {
            margin: 0;
            color: #fff;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .top-area .header-xl {
            margin-top: 20px;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .top-area .sub-header {
            font-weight: 300;
            margin-top: 5px;
            font-size: 2.8em !important;
        }

.form-container {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    float: right;
    padding: 20px 0;
    width: 320px;
}
```

Comment: because of flex property in container class, remove display: flex; It align all elements to the center of container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that I'm clear on what you're trying to do here, but you can use a `display: block;` on your `.top-area > .container` item to move it to the right within the green container. If you wanted it OUTSIDE of the green container and to the right in the red container, then you'd need to move it in the HTML. Right now it's contained in the div with the green border, rather than the red border.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I just tried to change around the the div, but no result. Do you have an idea how they should be turned around?

Comment: Is your goal to have the text centred within the green div and the yellow div outside of the green div and to the right in the red div? Need more clarification. Have you thought about using bootstrap columns?